# Record Time Out after the Time In - RFID Student Gate Pass ID System

Tags: vb.net

I am using VB.Net and MySql.
I have 3 tables named RFIDTag , TimeIn, TimeOut.

When I tap once it will record to the TimeIn, then when I tap twice the time must record to the TimeOut.

My work is already done in recording TimeIn and this is my logic to record TimeOut.

```
If (Count from the table where RFIDTag matches the textbox from vb.net) > 1 then
    If TimeOut = ""
          records Time into the TimeOut
    Else
          INSERT new record NEW row of TimeIn
Else
    INSERT new record NEW TimeIn
```

---

This is my code to record TimeIn.

```
    Using sqlcommand As New MySqlCommand
        With sqlcommand
            .CommandText = "INSERT INTO userrecord (RFIDTag, TimeIn) VALUES (@RFIDTag, @TimeIn)"
            .Connection = con
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@RFIDTag", TextBoxTag.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeIn", TimeIn)
        End With

        sqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using

    sqlreader = query.ExecuteReader
    sqlreader.Read()

    LabelName.Text = sqlreader.Item("FullName")
    LabelYearCourse.Text = sqlreader.Item("YearCourse")
    LabelIDNum.Text = sqlreader.Item("IDNumber")
    sqlreader.Close()


    TextBoxTag.Text = ""
    LabelStatus.Text = "IN"
    con.Close()
End If
```

This is my school project, I'm only the one who's using VB.Net, so I can`t ask my classmates. I also have done much research but I can't take it anymore. I will present this system in 3 days, but it's still not yet done=( I hope someone can lend me some help.

Comment: Ok - what is your particular problem? What is not working as expected and what would you expect if it is working. Not the general program outline, but specific sections of code?

Comment: Use `Option Explicit` and `Option Strict On`. In those bits where you don't have it working, show us what code you have used, not just some pseudo code that implies you want us to write your homework for you. I gave up homework decades ago.

Comment: put breakpoints into your If - Else statement. check if your statement is correct. the problem may not be  in the `record TimeIn`. And also, *Put your actual code* not just some pseudo code for us to determine what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

How about 2 tables in the database. Table RFIDTag with columns IDNumber as Primary Key, then FullName and YearCourse. Table TimeInOut with columns IDNumber as Foreign Key, then TimeIn and TimeOut.

Now keep a local Dictionary of students as they Log In.

```
Private LoggedInDictionary As Dictionary(Of Integer,DateTime)

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        LoggedInDictionary = New Dictionary(Of Integer, DateTime)
End Sub
```

From a Record button call either RecordLogIn or RecordLogOut depending on whether the student is in the LoggedInDictionary.

```
Private Sub btnRecord_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRecord.Click
        Dim key As Integer = CInt(TextBoxTag.Text)
        Dim value As DateTime
        'If the student is not in the dictionary
        If Not LoggedInDictionary.TryGetValue(key, value) Then
            RecordLogIn(key)
        Else
            RecordLogOut(key, value)
        End If
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        DisplayLoggedInStudents()
    End Sub

Private Sub RecordLogIn(StudentId As Integer)
        Dim ID As Integer = StudentId
        Dim LogInTime As DateTime = DateTime.Now
        LoggedInDictionary.Add(ID, LogInTime)
    End Sub

Private Sub RecordLogOut(ID As Integer, TimeIn As DateTime)
        Dim InsertQuery As String = "Insert into TimeInOut (IDNumber, TimeIn, TimeOut) Values (@ID, @TimeIn, @TimeOut);"
        Using con As New MySqlConnection("Your connection string")
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(InsertQuery, con)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeIn", TimeIn)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeOut", DateTime.Now)
                con.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        End Using
        LoggedInDictionary.Remove(ID)
    End Sub
```

At the end of the btnRecord sub the display of logged in students is updated.

```
Private Sub DisplayLoggedInStudents()
        For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, DateTime) In LoggedInDictionary
            Dim LoggedInStudents As String = $"Student Name: {GetStudentNameByID(item.Key)}, Student ID: {item.Key} Logged In Time: {item.Value}"
            ListBox1.Items.Add(LoggedInStudents)
        Next
    End Sub
```

The display uses GetStudentNameByID.

```
Private Function GetStudentNameByID(StudentID As Integer) As String
        Dim StudentName As String = ""
        Using con As New MySqlConnection("Your Connection String")
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select FullName From RFIDTag Where IDNumber = @ID;")
                cmd.Parameters.Add(@ID, StudentID)
                con.Open()
                StudentName = cmd.ExecuteScalar.ToString
            End Using
        End Using
        Return StudentName
    End Function
```

You can see the list logged in students and log them out at the end of the day. There are edge cases that will not work with this system. This code is not tested since to don't have your database.